# STL Container as private member. Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, segmentation-fault

I'm having a strange problem with a STL Container.

I have a class with a private member `std::map<string, string> _environment`. Why when I call `_environment["name"]="john"` in the class constructor (or anywhere), I get a `Segmentation fault`?

It should be the most common use of a STL container, shouldn't it?

Thanks!

Edit (more code):

**In shell.h:**

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Shell {
    public:
        Shell();
        Shell(const Shell& orig){};
        virtual ~Shell(){};

    private:
        ...
        ...
        std::map<string, string> _environment;
};
```

**In shell.cpp:**

```
Shell::Shell() {    
    _environment["shell"] = "myshell";    
    ...
}
```

The segmentation fault occurs in the line `_environment["shell"] = "myshell";`

Comment: Please post some example code, what you describe should of course work correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger to find out exactly where the code crashes?

Comment: Your code works for me, is there anything significant denoted by the `...`? Otherwise you might have to debug, I wouldn't think you're running out of memory, but...who knows?

Comment: This part of the code is perfectly fine

Comment: Really? I have some more things, but nothing special. Just 4 strings. The first line of the constructor is already that where I get the segmentation fault. I tested that if I declare the map into the constructor, it works fine!. I've also tested I with more stl containers and the same happens (I mean that I also get the seg fault if I declare it inside the class)...

Comment: I have been unable to recreate the segmentation fault on Mac OS X with g++ 4.2

Comment: Try using insert, if that helps.

Comment: Please post full code, since none of us can reproduce this problem you are seeing. Also, what platform, and compiler are you using? Maybe it's localized (hopefully not!)

Comment: Wop, I created a class just to test and it works good... I'll try to find out whats happening. Thank you!

Comment: Where is the object created? Is it created on the stack, on the heap, or is it a global variable?

Comment: I get the impression you are debugging by commenting out commands.  If you do this make sure that the objects you use do something useful (for example make them output a value to the terminal) otherwise the compiler will probably optimize your object out of existence and ruin your test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for Segmentation fault. And for simplify inserting I recommend to use boost::assign library, like this:

```
Shell::Shell() {
    using namespace boost::assign;
    insert( _environment )( "shell", "myshell" );    
    ...
}
```

This is more elegantly and more effectively.